# Django Open / Edit record instead of Creating new

Tags: python, django, post, get

I have a CustomerAddForm and a CustomerOverview HTML Table. When i add a new record in the CustomerAddForm it appears in the CustomerOverview HTML table. I also have the functionality to open existing customers from the CustomerOverview HTML by clicking on the customer name.

When i open an existing Customer it opens the Customer fine, but when i hit submit it saves the opened customer to a new record. If i hard code the Customer ID in the view it saves the given ID. So it looks like no id is pushed through when hitting submit.

Normal;

```
def customeradd(request, id = None)
```

With hardcoded id;

```
def customeradd(request, id = 1)
```

My views.py; where it seems after hitting submit request.method == 'POST' is always true. and the else statement is never run.

```
def customeradd(request, id = None): 
    if id:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk = id)
    else:
        customer = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerAddForm(request.POST or None, instance = customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Customer added succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customeroverview/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Customer save error, please check fields below')
    else:
        form = CustomerAddForm(instance = customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Customer edited succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customeroverview/')

    return render_to_response("customer-add.html",
                              {"customer_add_form": form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my forms.py (django-crispy-form)

```
class CustomerAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_action = '/customeradd/'     

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.helper.add_input(Button('cancel', 'Cancel'))

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'^customeroverview/$', 'customer.views.customeroverview', name='customeroverview'),
url(r'^customeradd/$', 'customer.views.customeradd', name='customeradd'),
url(r'^customeradd/(?P<id>\w+)$', 'customer.views.customeradd', name='customeredit'),
```

customer-add.html

```
{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy customer_add_form customer_add_form.helper %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what is your problem? what you want?

Comment: i want to edit and save the opened record. Now when i save it does not save the opened record, it creates a new one.

Comment: Why would you expect request.method to be anything other than POST when you submit the form? That's what submitting is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, i am quite new to django/python. Any suggestion in how to save the opened record instead of creating a new one?

Comment: You don't show your template, but it seems from your form init method that you are always submitting to /customeradd/, and therefore aren't passing in the ID when you submit.

Comment: in the template i just call the CustomerAddForm as it is a crispy-form the HTML is generated. Do you know how i can push the id in from the form action?

Comment: But the point is that your form action does not include the id when you're editing: you have specifically set it to always be the basic URL without id.

Comment: do you know how to include the id in the form action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
def customeradd(request, id=None): 
    if id:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk = id)
    else:
        customer = Customer()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerAddForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Customer added succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customeroverview/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Customer save error, please check fields below')
    else:
        form = CustomerAddForm(instance = customer)

    return render_to_response("customer-add.html",
                              {"customer_add_form": form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and replace

```
self.helper.form_action = '/customeradd/'
```

with

```
self.helper.form_action = ''
```

in your `forms.py`

Comment: I tried this before, it creates the error; customeradd() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). Because no id is given with submit.

Comment: check my edit. and remove `CustomerAddForm` constructor

Comment: I edited the views.py but still it creates a new record. I am not sure where to remove CustomerAddForm? I also checked crispy-forms website and they mention something like form.helper.form_action = reverse('/customeroverview/', args=[Customer.pk]) but this creates an error; Reverse for '/customeradd/' with arguments '(<property object at 0x00000000033D7278>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: keep in mind, if i set the id=1 it will save the alterations to id 1. So it seems no id is received in the view when clicking on submit on the form.

Comment: please add `customer-add.html` template in question.

Comment: customer-add.html is now in the question. (crispy-form)

Comment: replace `self.helper.form_action = '/customeradd/'` with `self.helper.form_action = '.'`

Comment: Again, the record saves as a new one. - shouldn't i add the customer.pk in the action (or something in that direction)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62775/discussion-between-hasan-ramezani-and-phicon).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific function to edit a customer:

```
@require_POST
@csrf_protect
def customeredit(request, id=None): 

    edited_customer = CustomerAddForm(request.POST)

    if edited_customer.is_valid():
        customer = edited_customer.save(commit=False)
        customer.id = id
        customer.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Customer edited succesfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/customeroverview/')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Customer save error, please check fields below')
        return render_to_response("customer-add.html",
                          {"customer_add_form": edited_customer},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

That means you need to modify `urls.py`

```
url(r'^customeredit/(?P<id>\w+)$', 'customer.views.customeraedit', name='customeredit'),
```

Comment: Thank you, but this makes no difference.